# How do I access a database with open source swift?

Tags: database, swift, ubuntu

I have build an app in swift that downloads content from my ubuntu server. The content on my server is build with help of some php/javascript scripts and stored in a mysql database, before it is send to the app. However I can't actually test this content, until I download it on the app, which causes me to spend hours on hours testing all the input.

I could make my workflow flow 10x faster if I could test it on the server. Luckily Apple released open source swift half a year ago, so I figured I could just copy the relevant swift code from my app to the server.

However it doesn't seem there is any way to access my database with open source swift and neither is NSURLSession.sharedSession() implemented yet, so I have no idea how to access my database on my server.

My database is mysql, but I wouldn't mind changing it to sqlite or some other type of database, if that would help solve the problem.

So there is my question, how do I access a database with open source swift on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I found a package that gives me access to a mysql database from swift:
https://github.com/novi/mysql-swift

I found some other similar packages as well, but I didn't test any of those, so I don't know whether they are any good.